# What to do to make 50 concurrent calls to Flask app deployed on AWS?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask, load-testing

I am using the following python script to test an application that is running on an AWS instance,

```
import sys
import requests
import logging
import random
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import os
import time


logger = logging.getLogger('Intrudx')
handle = logging.FileHandler('Intrudx.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
handle.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handle)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


loop_count = int(sys.argv[1])
sleep_time = int(sys.argv[2])


# CHECKING THE HEARTBEAT
def heartbeat(SessionID, SiteID):
    logger.info("Starting heartbeat thread")
    try:
        heart_url = 'http://ec2-instance-address.com/license/heartbeat'
        heart_result = requests.post(heart_url, json={
                                                     "SessionID":str(SessionID),
                                                     "SiteID" : str(SiteID)
                                                      })
        if heart_result.status_code is 500:
            logger.error("Heartbeat Failed with 500")
            return "We Got 500"
        response_text = heart_result.json()["ResponseText"]
        logger.info("Heartbeat: "+str(response_text))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Heartbeat Failed"+str(e))


# FINDING THE SERVER IP
def ip(SessionID):
    logger.info("Starting get server info thread")
    try:
        get_server_url = 'http://ec2-instance-address.com/server/getStreamingServer'
        get_server_result = requests.post(get_server_url, json={"SessionID": str(SessionID)})
        result_code = get_server_result.status_code
        if result_code is 500:
            logger.error("GetStreamingServerInfo: " + "Failed")
            return "We Got 500"
        response_text = get_server_result.json()["ResponseText"]
        logger.info("GetStreamingServerInfo: " + str(response_text))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("GetStreamingServerInfo: " + str(e))


def main():
    for i in range(loop_count):
        # LOGIN
        try:
            login_url = 'http://ec2-instance-address.com/user/login'
            login_result = requests.post(login_url, json={
                                                            "AccountName": "Account1",
                                                            "UserID": "user2",
                                                            "UserPassword": "test"
                                                         })
            result_code = login_result.status_code
            if result_code is 500:
                logger.error("Login: "+"Failed")
                return "We Got 500"
            SessionID = login_result.json()["SessionID"]
            response_text = login_result.json()["ResponseText"]
            logger.info("Login: "+str(response_text)+": "+ str(SessionID))
            print(str(SessionID)+str(response_text))

        except Exception as e:
            result_code = str(e)
            logger.error("Login: "+str(e))

        # GET NEW SITE
        try:
            get_new_site_url = 'http://ec2-instance-address.com/license/getNewSite'
            get_new_site_result = requests.post(get_new_site_url, json={"SessionID": str(SessionID)})
            result_code = get_new_site_result.status_code
            if result_code is 500:
                logger.error("Login: " + "Failed")
                return "We Got 500"
            response_text = get_new_site_result.json()["ResponseText"]
            site_id = get_new_site_result.json()["NewSiteID"]
            logger.info("getNewSite: "+str(response_text)+": "+str(site_id))

        except Exception as e:
            result_code = str(e)


             logger.error("getNewSite"+str(e))


        # STARTING HEARTBEAT THREAD
        try:
            threading.Thread(target=heartbeat(SessionID, site_id), args=(SessionID, site_id,)).start()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Problem starting thread: "+str(e))

        # STARTING GET SERVER INFO THREAD
        try:
            threading.Thread(target=ip(SessionID), args=(SessionID)).start()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Problem while starting Get Server Info Thread"+str(e))
```

This script is using just one user, creating one session/connection with the server to make API calls.

In a similar way, I want to test the application with 50 or 100 different users (With different accounts/credentials) connected to the server making API calls. Like 50 or 100 users are concurrently using the application. So I can ensure that the application is handling 50 users properly.

How can I do this kind of testing with a script?

**Update:** Most of the routes are hidden, they need @login_required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you try [Bees With Machine Guns](https://github.com/newsapps/beeswithmachineguns).  Its a python script that will launch micro EC2 instances and send many requests from these instances to your application.  This will simulate a large surge in traffic for performance testing.

I heard about it from [AWS training videos on CBT Nuggets](https://www.cbtnuggets.com/it-training/amazon-aws-certified-sysops-administrator-associate).  The instructor was effective using it to trigger auto scaling and load test his configuration.

Good luck.

Comment: Almost all of the API routes (except for login and register) are hidden, they need @login_required. How would it hit those APIs?

Comment: Thanks, mate. It did give me an idea and I wrote my own small library.

Answer (score 1):

You could try our little tool k6 also: https://github.com/loadimpact/k6

You script the behaviour of the virtual users using JavaScript, so it is quite easy to get 50 different users logging in with different credentials. Would look something like this (this code is going to need debugging though :)

```
import http from "k6/http";

let login_url = "http://ec2-instance-address.com/user/login";
let get_new_site_url = "http://ec2-instance-address.com/license/getNewSite";
let credentials = [
    { "account": "Account1", "username": "joe", "password": "secret" },
    { "account": "Account2", "username": "jane", "password": "verysecret" }
];

export default function() {
  let session_id = doLogin();
  let response = doGetNewSite(session_id);
  let response_text = response["ResponseText"];
  let new_site_id = response["NewSiteID"];
  for (i = 0; i < loop_count; i++) {
    // do heartbeat stuff?
  }
}

function doLogin() {
  let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * credentials.length);
  let post_body = {
    "AccountName": credentials[index]["account"],
    "UserID": credentials[index]["username"],
    "UserPassword": credentials[index]["password"]
  };
  let http_headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };
  let res = http.post(login_url, JSON.stringify(post_body), { headers: http_headers });
  check(res, {
    "Response code is 200": (r) => r.status == 200,
    "Login successful": (r) => JSON.parse(r.body).hasOwnProperty("SessionID")
  });
  return JSON.parse(res.body)["SessionID"];
}

function doGetNewSite(session_id) {
  let http_headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };
  let post_body = { "SessionID": session_id };
  let res = http.post(get_new_site_url, JSON.strjngify(post_body), { headers: http_headers });
  check(res, {
    "Status code was 200": (r) => r.status == 200,
    "Got response text": (r) => JSON.parse(r.body).hasOwnProperty("ResponseText"),
    "Got new site id": (r) => JSON.parse(r.body).hasOwnProperty("NewSiteID")
  });
  return JSON.parse(res.body);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have never coded in JS and I was in immediate need so I wrote my own Script in Python.